# Salesforce Marketing Cloud/Exact Target API Authorization Endpoint for OAuth Authorization Code Workflow?

Tags: oauth

Does anybody know it?  Their documentation discusses getting a user token [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/exacttarget_dev_use_api_directly.htm) and [here](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/marketing-cloud-apps/using-app-center-to-create-an-app.html), but that's not what I need.  The documentation clearly states on these pages linked about that "it is recommended that you utilize an Authorization Code or Implicit Grant OAuth flow instead."

The documentation does not include the authorization endpoint.  Something like `https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/oauth/authorize?client_id=#&callback_url=url`  You know, something like that but not that because that doesn't work.

Comment: So, I contacted SMC and they looked into it and told me that the REST API does not support this grant type.  :(

Comment: Thank you. So they are not using proper OAuth?